# How do I change Outlook's threaded view to only one line

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Outlook in Office 365 version 1701 build 776.2902

So right now, I see two lines and really, I prefer to never see more than one in a tree view of any sort. I'd really prefer something with a decent threaded view but of course, corporate disagrees. In this case when I'm looking at the threaded view and have the tree open, I have a two line header for the tree where the fonts are way too large. I want it down to one small line. How can I achieve this?

I'm seeing two fields. One is the From field and the other is the Subject line. I prefer to see only subject line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the From field by right-clicking the column header and selecting "Remove This Column". You can use View tab | View Settings | Other Settings to change the Row Font... if you find that too large, you can also turn on Always use single-line layout under Other Options on the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: I eventually discovered that it switches to one line if you stretch the panel out far enough to the right. This did not help though because then I lost the indentation provided in threaded view. Bottom line seems to be that Outlook's threaded view just plain blows. Not a surprise since that is what I'd heard a long time ago anyway. I was just hoping someone had come to their senses.

Comment: Weirdly, I right-clicked the row header and selected "View Settings | Columns | Reset current view". Several things changed but I got indenting back.